# Visual Studio Code - Docker Tutorial - Flask Python App Error

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile

I built the simple flask app from the [tutorial](https://github.com/microsoft/python-sample-vscode-flask-tutorial/), and I'm trying to follow the Docker [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-python).

When I run the app with/without debugger it work if I choose the "Python: Flask" for example.

But if I choose like the tutorial suggest the "Docker: Python - Flask" it crashes, with the following popup:

[crash pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekQF0.png)

Dockerfile:

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.10-slim

EXPOSE 5000

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "hello_app\__init__:app"]
```

launch.json file:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "hello_app.webapp",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "1"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "jinja": true,
            "justMyCode": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Docker: Python - Flask",
            "type": "docker",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
            "python": {
                "pathMappings": [
                    {
                        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                        "remoteRoot": "/app"
                    }
                ],
                "projectType": "flask"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**All of the project files are 100% the same as in the full app from the tutorial GitHub I provided.**

I tried searching answer in the web and on Stack Overflow, but none helped me. Some examples of questions I saw that did not solved my problem:

- [cannot run python flask app in docker with vscode (from tutorial)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68412787/cannot-run-python-flask-app-in-docker-with-vscode-from-tutorial?newreg=2566460cf0374d55b8ef00eaecc03bd9)
- [VSCode: The Python path in your debug configuration is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66698247/vscode-the-python-path-in-your-debug-configuration-is-invalid)
- [Error debugging Python in VS Code: "pythonPath" is not valid if "python" is specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75439217/error-debugging-python-in-vs-code-pythonpath-is-not-valid-if-python-is-spec)
- [VScode,The Python path in your debug configuration is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73012000/vscode-the-python-path-in-your-debug-configuration-is-invalid)

---

### Update 1:

Docker debug backtrace:

```
 *  Executing task: docker-build 

> docker image build --pull --file "C:\Users\foodmarket\Desktop\DockerImage/Dockerfile" --tag "dockerimage:latest" --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio-code" "C:\Users\foodmarket\Desktop\DockerImage" <

#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 952B 0.0s done
#1 DONE 0.1s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 transferring context: 409B 0.0s done
#2 DONE 0.1s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10-slim
#3 DONE 0.6s

#4 [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.10-slim@sha256:ef44c53813f71871130462fcd1cf77df9a3a468ed7730b402e1216e21ed8fe4f
#4 DONE 0.0s

#5 [internal] load build context
#5 transferring context: 607B 0.0s done
#5 DONE 0.1s

#6 [2/6] COPY requirements.txt .
#6 CACHED

#7 [3/6] RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
#7 CACHED

#8 [4/6] WORKDIR /app
#8 CACHED

#9 [5/6] COPY . /app
#9 CACHED

#10 [6/6] RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
#10 CACHED

#11 exporting to image
#11 exporting layers done
#11 writing image sha256:5bd436502de14783be9737a79ba5e2d47a1081699e7478bf50d423daa395e3f0 0.0s done
#11 naming to docker.io/library/dockerimage:latest 0.0s done
#11 DONE 0.0s
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

 *  Executing task: docker-run: debug 

> docker container run --detach --tty --name "dockerimage-dev" --publish-all --mount "type=bind,source=c:\Users\foodmarket\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy,destination=/debugpy,readonly" --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio-code" --env "FLASK_APP=hello_app\__init__.py" --entrypoint "python3" dockerimage:latest <

5872355623f30fa5e812d13ef0ad7c674f9100a44da233336abf9bedb7e48d2d
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

**If any other data in needed, comment it and I'll add everything, please.**

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the backtrace from the application in plain text (not an image) and directly in the question (not behind a link)?

Comment: I added a photo just for the popup because it didn't let me copy the text from it.
I added the backtrace from the docker debug build to the question as you asked. @DavidMaze